# Shopify: What apps to use/How to create personalized logged in experience?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I have a shopify store where I sell products currently. I want to create a larger logged in experience within shopify. To be more concrete, we sell at home biomarker testing kits that we mail to customers and then they mail them back to us. I want them to be able to log into shopify and see personalized results (i.e., "The result of your lab test is XX") and display some simple graphs. I've heard this is possible with shopify - how do I get started? Are there specific apps I should look at?

I do have a software/programming background, but I am new to shopify.

Answer (score 0):

With Shopify and logged-in customers, they are able to access anything special in their customer account Liquid templates. Using your smarts, load their biomarker data to some DB along with their Shopify customer ID. You can use Shopify Apps to make custom code load in the store customer section. So when a logged-in customer navigates to their customer account page in Shopify, your custom App code can display their biomarker data. I have been doing this kind of thing with Shopify for 17 years. Standard web app stuff. You want to go custom here, you are not going to download some canned App from Shopify App store to solve your issue here, but then again, maybe you will. All depends on your tolerances for data safety and the like.